# How to connect icecast server using java

Tags: java

I want to start, stop and stream icecast server using java. And Is it possible to integrate icecast server to J2EE web application?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Java libshout binding, such as this one: https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/libshout-java (MIT license), to control an Icecast server from a Java application.

From [the Iceast FAQ](http://icecast.org/faq/):

> What is libshout?
>
> libshout is a library for communicating with and sending data to an Icecast server. It handles the socket connection, the timing of the data, and prevents bad data from getting to the Icecast server.